# 18.04 lost all settings

Tags: gnome, 18.04, settings

I installed 18.04.1 from scratch on my desktop computer and used settings and gnome-tweak-tool to set several of my preferences, like icon sizes, mouse sloppy focus, and many more. After I rebooted my machine, they all disappeared and the system does not allow me to change them again. For instance, I cannot change icon size or add an application to my favorites. It even lost my keyboard layout -- I am using a foreign language keyboard which worked perfectly before reboot.

Any help will be appreciated -- I am desperate!

**Additional info as requested:**

(1) I was logged in as myself. Apparently all my applications work correctly but I cannot configure anything!

(2) Output from df -h:

```
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           790M  1.9M  788M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       450G   51G  376G  12% /
tmpfs           3.9G   33M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop2      5.0M  5.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/42
/dev/loop3       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/loop4       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/pdftk/9
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop6       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
/dev/loop7       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
/dev/loop8      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop9       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5548
/dev/loop10      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop11      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop12      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop13     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop14     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop0      4.8M  4.8M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/49
/dev/loop15      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop16      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/sda1       511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           790M   16K  790M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           790M   16K  790M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb        459G   52G  384G  12% /media/myself/seagate500
/dev/loop17     5.0M  5.0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/50
```

(3) Output from cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f345d4c5-7a21-4f42-8991-49330aecb1d9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=394E-C62F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of the commands `df -h` and `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: Are you sure you weren't logged in a guest as opposed the admin user. Guest account changes don't normally remain persistent across users.